# how can i set a variable in a array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, variables

i have the problem where i set a variable but it creates a new one instead, i am not quite sure what is going on here. I have tried using global, setting the variables first and tried to use a tupple but just can't get it working. but this is the problem:

```
>>> variable = 1
>>> variableList = [variable]
>>> variableList[0] = 2
>>> print(variable)
1
```

as you can see it variable stays 1 although i set it to 2, is there a easy way to fix this?

Comment: Maybe `variable` remains the same because .... you never change it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing `variableList = [variable]` actually created a new reference(`variableList[0]`) to the object `1`. And when you did `variableList[0] = 2`, it removed one reference from `1` and assigned `variableList[0]` to 2. So, using an assignment you can never modify other references.

```
>>> import sys
>>> variable = 1000
>>> sys.getrefcount(variable) 
2
>>> variableList = [variable]  
>>> sys.getrefcount(variable)  # Reference count increased by 1
3
>>> variableList[0] = 2        
>>> sys.getrefcount(variable)   #Reference count decreased by 1
2
```

In fact even you've used `+=`, that too wouldn't have affected `variable` because you don't modify a immutable object, you simply assign a new object to that variable name.

```
>>> a = 100
>>> b = a
>>> b += 10 #This too only affects b
>>> a
100
>>> b
110
```

But, if `variable` points to a mutable object and you perform some in-place operation on that object from either `variable` or `variableList[0]`, then you'll see that both of them have changed.

```
>>> a = []
>>> b = [a]
>>> b[0].append(1)  #in-place operation on a mutable object affects all references
>>> a
[1]
>>> b
[[1]]
```

Comment: well this helps to know, but i thought it should have been possible because it would work if variable had been a list and i would have set a value of that list through a list

Comment: @user3080469 No, A simple assignment will not work even if we change `variable` to a list. Try: `variable = []; x = [variable]; x[0] = 10;print variable;` The point is, it is not possible to modify the other references to an object when you assign one of the references to something else.

Answer (score 1):

You're reassigning the `0th` element of the **list** (not Array), to the Integer 2, you are *not* overwriting the variable `variable`.

```
>>> variable = 1
>>> variableList = [variable]
>>> variableList[0] = 2
>>> print(variable)
>>> 1
>>> print(variableList)
[2]
```

It suggest you also look up mutability, as it's important to note that integers are [immutable](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html):

> The value of some objects can change. Objects whose value can change are said to be mutable; objects whose value is unchangeable once they are created are called immutable.

Answer (score 1):

you don't set `variable`. you just change `variableList` content.

`variableList[0]` it's a variable like `variable` so the command `variableList = [variable]` just copy its value.

it is just like this:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = a
>>> b = 2
>>> print(a)
1
```

Answer (score -3):

When you did :variableList = [variable]
you created the first element of veribleList and made its value to balue of variable but it dont makes this first element a varible you just coppied its value so when you change variableList[0] it has nothing to do with variable